# rewriting url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, friendly-url, seo

I'm pretty new to .htaccess and I'm trying to rewrite the following URL structure:

[http://www.example.com/groups/menu.php?id=This is Group Name With Number 25](http://www.example.com/groups/menu.php?id=This+is+Group+Name+With+Number+25)

into:

http://www.example.com/groups/this-is-group-name-with-number-25/

as you can see I need to include `-` as a separator instead of empty spaces, and I also need to have all characters be lowercase, but allow numbers.

Now since "This is Group Name With Number 25" is user-generated, do I need to make any additional changes within my PHP script so it can generate that kind of URL in web browser or will the .htaccess file handle everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use external rewriting for such things. This one will be a simple few-line perl script. See apache documentation for "External Rewriting Program".

```
RewriteMap mapname prg:/path/to/program
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be handling a path creation like that in PHP, before it even gets sent to the HTML and into an anchor for someone to click on. Not only does it contain spaces which will get converted into `%20` and make the URL unreadable, it contains uppercase letters!

There is no efficient way to lowercase your letters and replace all the spaces with dashes efficiently. Most methods will use a bunch of extra HTTP requests.